# Guice provide instance of implicit dynamic subclass

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

i need help, i have an `AbstractModule` that have a list of subclasses the need to use a single provider.

The classes i am providing are loaded dynamically as a plugin

how can i achieve this

```
interface Plugin {X getX();}

class Plugin1 implements Plugin {X getX() {return X1;}}
class Plugin2 implements Plugin {X getX() {return X2;}}


public class ThreadDataModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
       //x_list will contain Plugin1,Plugin2,Plugin3 classes 
       for(Plugin plugin : plugin_list_classes) {
         ->> how can i bind  'plugin.getX().class to XProvider' 
       }
    }

    public class XProvider implements Provider<X> {
        public X get() {
            return Get Plugin at Thread.getX()
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you

============================

i did something like this to solve this, now each plugin has to implement the `getXProvider` method ‍♂️. Is there a more elegant way ?

```
interface Plugin {
   X getX();
   public Provider getXProvider(Callable callable);
}

class Plugin1 implements Plugin {
    public X getX() {return new X1;}

    @Override
    public Provider getXProvider(Callable callable) {
        return new Provider<X1>() {
            @Override
            public X1 get() {
                try {
                    return (X1) callable.call();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }
        }
    };
}



public class ThreadDataModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
       //x_list will contain Plugin1,Plugin2,Plugin3 classes 
       for(Plugin plugin : plugin_list_classes) {
         bind(plugin.getX().getClass()).toProvider((javax.inject.Provider)plugin.getXProvider(()-> {
            return m_threadIndexToDependencies.get(m_threadIndex).X;
           }));
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that if you want to implement a custom provider, you don't need to bind in configure. Either one way, or another.

Not sure what is a relationship between your classes in the x_list_classes, and threads. Is there a single class, per thread?

If yes, then how do you want to do the mapping?

In general, you can do in-scope binding, so that there will be a single instance, create for each scope:

https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Scopes

I think that you can make Thread a scope too.

Or maybe you want to add custom annotations for each class, so that different instance of X can be annotated for injection, like this:

```
@Inject
public SomeClass(@Foo X x) {}
```

And then you need to bind using annotatedWith():

```
bind(X.class).annotatedWith(Foo.class).to(X1.classs);
```

You need to create annotation itself too, see example:

https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/BindingAnnotations

Answer (score 1):

You want `bind(...).toProvider(...)`:

```
for (Class<?> targetType : ...) {
    bind(targetType).toProvider(new XProvider(...));
}
```

If you want to inject other dependencies into your `XProvider` class, you can grab providers for them from the binder with `Binder.getProvider()` (or `AbstractModule.getProvider()`, if you're inside a subclass of `AbstractModule`), or you could make your `XProvider` itself injectable.

Normally, making `XProvider` itself injectable is the simpler solution (just do `bind(Foo.class).toProvider(FooProvider.class)`), but it sounds like you have more than one output type that you want to provide using similar logic, for which you probably want to instantiate provider objects manually.